# Zend Route XML config does not work as expected

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

Below is my routes.xml which gets loaded in my Zend Framework app. There are two routes, one should match the url `/aanbod/tekoop/huis` and the other should match `/aanbod/200/gerenoveerde-woning`

The problem is that both these example urls end up at the detail action while the first one should end up at the index action.

Can anyone clarify what's wrong with this routing setup?

```
<routes>

    <property_overview type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route">
        <route>/aanbod/:category/:type</route>
        <reqs category="(tekoop|tehuur)" />
        <reqs type="[A-Za-z0-9]+" />
        <defaults module="frontend" controller="property" action="index" />
    </property_overview>

    <property_detail type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route">
        <route>/aanbod/:propertyid/:slug</route>
        <reqs propertyid="[0-9]+" />
        <reqs slug="(^\s)+" />
        <defaults module="frontend" controller="property" action="detail" />
    </property_detail>

</routes>
```

Comment: Don't start your routes with a forward slash. The framework takes care of the base URL prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<routes>

    <property_overview type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route">
        <route>aanbod/:category/:type</route>
        <reqs category="(tekoop|tehuur)" type="[A-Za-z0-9]+" />
        <defaults module="frontend" controller="property" action="index" />
    </property_overview>

    <property_detail type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route">
        <route>aanbod/:propertyid/:slug</route>
        <reqs propertyid="[0-9]+" slug="[^\s]+" />
        <defaults module="frontend" controller="property" action="detail" />
    </property_detail>

</routes>
```

What I've changed:

- You should only have one 'reqs' element - add the different requirements as attributes of this. This is the main reason why your routes weren't working, as only one of the reqs was being used in each route
- Remove the initial slash - this serves no purpose
- Changed the slug pattern to `[^\s]+` which means 'any character other than a space, one or more times', I think this is what you meant.

Comment: Works perfectly, the multiple request tags indeed were the problem! Thanks for the crystalclear answer!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the `reqs` parameter to help identify the route for `Zend_Controller_Router_Route`. In your case, your routes are identical and as the route stack is LIFO, the "detail" one takes precedence.

Perhaps try using [`Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex) instead.

I'm having a hard time finding the configuration method for the regex router but in code it would look something like

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'aanbod/(tekoop|tehuur)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)',
    array('controller' => 'property', 'action' => 'index', 'module' => 'frontend'),
    array(1 => 'category', 2 => 'type')
);

$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    'aanbod/(\d+)/(\S+)',
    array('controller' => 'property', 'action' => 'detail', 'module' => 'frontend'),
    array(1 => 'propertyid', 2 => 'slug')
);
```